# Custom delegate alwayse nil

Tags: swift, delegates

I followed exactly this [tutorial](http://stephenradford.me/creating-a-delegate-in-swift/) to create a custom delegate.

I create the delegate

```
protocol UserTableViewDelegate: class {

    func helpClicked()
}
```

Then in class `HelpTableViewCell`

weak var delegate: UserTableViewDelegate?

```
@IBAction func helpButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
delegate?.helpClicked()
}
```

In class `UserTableViewController` I conform to the delegate `UserTableViewDelegate` and then

```
func helpClicked() {
}
```

However the function never get called. The delegate variable in class `HelpTableViewCell` is always nil and `delegate?.helpClicked()` has no effect.

Comment: Where u Implemeted protocol?

Comment: where you set the delegate, you did not set the delegate, that's why it is not get called

Comment: In you UserTableViewController did you set the HelpTableViewCell delegate to = self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The delegate variable in class HelpTableViewCell is always nil and delegate?.helpClicked() has no effect.

That's because you haven't created a delegate at all. A delegate is an object that implements a particular set of delegate methods. You're not creating any such object, at least in the code you've shown.

> I create the delegate

No, you've defined a delegate protocol. You haven't instantiated a class that adopts that protocol. The tutorial that you referenced is pretty sloppy in the language that it uses and doesn't really distinguish between the `delegate protocol`, i.e. the set of methods that a given kind of delegate is expected to implement, and the *delegate* itself, i.e. the particular object that provides those methods to the delegator.

> In class UserTableViewController I conform to the delegate UserTableViewDelegate and then

That's the right idea, but if the expression `delegate?.helpClicked()` doesn't get called because `delegate` is nil, then you must have failed to assign the controller as the table's delegate. Sometimes the delegate can be assigned in a storyboard, the same way you'd connect a view controller to its view. You could do that if the table in question uses static cells, where all the cells are created in the storyboard. Just make HelpTableViewCell's `delegate` an IBOutlet and then connect it to the UserTableViewController. More often, though, table cells are dynamic and configured at run time; in that case, you'll want to set the `delegate` property for your HelpTableViewCell when you configure the cell, most likely in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

That said, you may not need to bother with delegation at all in the case you've described. A table view's delegate is already informed when the user interacts with a cell. You don't say here whether you're working in iOS or MacOS, but it doesn't matter: both UITableViewDelegate (iOS) and NSTableViewDelegate (macOS) have methods that are called when a cell is tapped or clicked. Cells are usually pretty lightweight objects -- they generally worry mostly about displaying their content properly and leave user interaction to the table's delegate (which is almost always the view controller).

Answer (score 0):

Within `UserTableViewController` you also need to set the delegate property like below -

nameofyourCustomcellObject.delegate = self